# Isomorphism between two structures

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

I am reading the solution of b(ii):
[image]
Solution:
[image]
I am very confused from the start of the solution. To show isomorphism we want to prove there is a bijective function $\alpha: \mathcal A_2\to \mathcal B_2$ s.t. for all $a_1,a_2\in \mathcal A_2$, $a_1 =_A a_2$ iff $\alpha(a)=_B \alpha(b)$? I am not sure I understand the solution correctly: $f$ is inkective in both structures, and 1 is the unique fixed point. But then, even if $x\in im f$ shouldn't $x, f(x), f(f(x))...$ still be distinct? How is this enough to give an isomorphism? Does this try to construct $\alpha$ by $\alpha(f_A(x))=f_B(x)$ if $x$ is one of $y,f_A(y),f_A(f_A(y))...$ for some fixed $y$? If it is this case,  what will happen to $f_A(y')$ for $y'\neq y$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do not rely on embedded images for your question to make sense. If you expect people to take the time to type out answers to your questions, you can take the time to type out the full text of the question (in this case, just part (ii) and the solution would suffice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a picture will help. Here is $A_2$:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
1 \\ \\
2 @>{f}>> 4 @>{f}>> 16 @>{f}>> \dots\\\\
3 @>{f}>> 9 @>{f}>> 81 @>{f}>> \dots\\\\
5 @>{f}>> 25 @>{f}>> 625 @>{f}>>\dots \\\\
\vdots & &  \vdots & & \vdots
\end{CD}$$

... and here is $B_2$:
$$\begin{CD}
1 \\ \\
2 @>{f}>> 8 @>{f}>> 512 @>{f}>>\dots\\\\
3 @>{f}>> 27 @>{f}>> 19683 @>{f}>>\dots\\\\
4 @>{f}>> 64 @>{f}>> 262144 @>{f}>>\dots\\\\
\vdots & &  \vdots & & \vdots
\end{CD}$$
Isn't it clear that they're isomorphic?

---

To write a careful proof, the key point is the parenthetical at the end: any bijection between then points not in the image (those are the leftmost columns, excluding $1$, in my pictures of $A_2$ and $B_2$) extends in a unique way to an isomorphism.

Let $C\subseteq A_2$ be the set of points not in the image of $f$. Note that $C$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (there are infinitely many non-squares in $\mathbb{N}$), hence $C$ is countably infinite.

Let $D\subseteq B_2$ be the set of points not in the image of $f$. Again, $D$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (there are infinitely many non-cubes in $\mathbb{N}$), hence $D$ is countably infinite.

Since $C$ and $D$ are both countably infinite, we can fix a bijection $\beta\colon C\to D$.

Now we'd like to extend $\beta$ to an isomorphism. Let $n\in A_2$ with $n\neq 1$. Then $n = f^k(c)$ for some unique $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c\in C$. [Try to prove this yourself. In the solution, this is stated as "the points $x$, $f(x)$, $f(f(x))$, $\dots$ are all distinct and sets like this partition $\mathbb{N}$ (apart from the fixed point".] Note that we allow $k = 0$, in the case $n = c\in C$.

If we want $\alpha$ to be an isomorphism and extend $\beta$, $\alpha$ must map the unique fixed point to the unique fixed point ($1\mapsto 1$), and we must set $\alpha(f^k(c)) = f^k(\alpha(c)) = f^k(\beta(c))$. So there is only one possible way to define $\alpha$: $$\alpha(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x = 1\\
f^k(\beta(c)) &\text{if }x = f^k(c)\text{ with }c\in C\end{cases}$$

I'll leave it to you to check that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Just few more questions. First, is it correct that $f^k(\beta(c))=\beta(f^k(c))$? Further, isn't the second case of the way you define $\alpha$ includes the case $x=1$? And the way we partition $\mathbb N$ is: $1,3,4,9,16,.....$?

Comment: (1) If $n$ is not in the image of $f$, i.e., $n\in C$, then $n = f^0(n)$, so we define $\alpha(n) = f^0(\beta(n)) = \beta(n)$. (2) When $k>0$, the statement $f^k(\beta(c)) = \beta(f^k(c))$ doesn't even make sense. Te domain of $\beta$ is $C = \mathbb{N}\setminus \mathrm{im}(f)$, but $f^k(c)\in \mathrm{im}(f)$, so $\beta(f^k(c))$ is not defined. This is why we need to *extend* $\beta$ to an isomorphism by defining $\alpha$. (3) "isn't the second case of the way you define $\alpha$ includes the case $x = 1$?" No, because there is no $c\in C$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 = f^k(c)$.

Comment: (4) "And the way we partition $\mathbb{N}$ is: $1,3,4,9,16,\dots$" I fail to even see a pattern in this sequence of numbers, much less its relevance for the problem at hand. The partition referred to in the solution in your post is the partition into the rows of the diagrams I drew. i.e., in $A_2$, $\mathbb{N}$ is partitioned into the sets $\{2,4,16,\dots\}, \{3,9,81,\dots\}, \{5, 25, 625,\dots\},\dots $.